# How to use the highest values for a certain criteria to sort the list?

Tags: mysql, sql

For the following data in a table, I want to get the highest balance for each person and then sort the result in descending order of that highest balance:

```
|---------id--------|--------name--------|--------balance--------

          1         |        Tom         |      10
          2         |        Bob         |      20
          3         |        Ace         |      60
          4         |        Tom         |      45
          5         |        Ace         |      35
          6         |        Tom         |      75
          7         |        Dan         |      15
          8         |        Dan         |      95
          9         |        Tom         |      40
          10        |        Dan         |      30
          11        |        Bob         |      65
          12        |        Dan         |      55
          13        |        Bob         |      50
```

the expected result is (For descending order):

```
|--------id---------|--------name--------|--------balance--------

          8         |        Dan         |      95
          6         |        Tom         |      75
          11        |        Bob         |      65
          3         |        Ace         |      60
```

What would be the mySQL query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe like this:

```
select pid, name, max(balance) as highest_balance from my_table
group by pid, name
order by max(balance) desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MAX()` and order by

```
SELECT id,name,MAX(balance) AS  balance
FROM table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY balance DESC
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/198f00/4)

Comment: I tried this & it works only if ORDER BY is also done using MAX(). Can you confirm?

Comment: No it will order without using max again in order by

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT(b1.pid), b1.name, b1.balance FROM balance b1 WHERE balance = (SELECT MAX(b2.balance) FROM balance b2 WHERE b1.pid = b2.pid) ORDER BY balance DESC

OR

SELECT pid, name, MAX(balance) FROM balance GROUP BY pid ORDER BY balance DESC